# Can't install LIRC. Missing paths and files

Tags: lirc

I'm installing LIRC on my Raspberry Pi 3B.

I ran:

```
apt-get install lirc
apt-get install lirc-x
```

Then I followed a number of web examples:
[Energenie ener314-ir - The IR Board I'm using](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:dcb3_jh2LDgJ:https://energenie4u.co.uk/res/pdfs/ENER314-IR_User_guide_V3.pdf%20&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk%20but%20I%20fall%20down%20when%20they%20say:)
[LIRC - Raspberry Pi](http://www.etcwiki.org/wiki/LIRC_-_Raspberry_Pi)
and quite a few others.

However, I fall down on each one as they all say at some point:

> edit your /etc/modules

and

> /etc/lirc/hardware.conf

I don't have these files.
I don't even have an /etc/lirc/ folder.

I'm a new to Raspbian and Linux in general so I'm not sure how to proceed to debug this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everybody has `/etc/modules`, it's a system file. You are probably not looking in the correct location.

Basically, from the root of the file system are a number of system folders, and a folder called `home`. Home is where YOUR files and folders are, including `Downloads`, `Documents` and such. You need to go into the system folder called `etc`. The simplest way to do this is via the command line.

1. Open a terminal. Look for a black rectangle icon called term.
2. Choose your text editor and launch it by typing this command:

`sudo name_of_text_editor /etc/modules`

Some people use `leaf`, some people use `nano`, some people use `vi`. If your text editor doesn't launch, use `gksudo` instead of `sudo`.

Comment: Yes that worked.
I think I confused files with folders